# Update all dropdown boxes with the same class

Tags: javascript

**Brief**

I am attempting to change the value of all dropdown boxes with the class of **admin__control-select** to **remove** when the **Remove All** button is pressed

**Issue**

The below code appears to work, but only updates the value of the first select box. I tried using [querySelectorAll](https://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) but that doesn't work at all.

**Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectFunction = function() {
        document.querySelector('.admin__control-select').value = "remove";
    };
</script>

<select class="admin__control-select">
    <option value="defaultValue">Default</option>
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>  
    <option value="remove">Remove</option>
</select>

<select class="admin__control-select">
    <option value="defaultValue">Default</option>
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="remove">Remove</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Remove All" onclick="selectFunction()" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll()`, it returns an Array with matched elements.

Then, traverse the array with `for()`.

```
var elms = document.querySelectorAll('.admin__control-select');
for(var i=0; i<elms.length; i++){
  elms[i].value ='remove';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectFunction = function() {
        var selects = document.querySelectorAll('.admin__control-select');
        selects.forEach(s => s.value = 'remove');
    };
</script>

<select class="admin__control-select">
    <option value="defaultValue">Default</option>
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>  
    <option value="remove">Remove</option>
</select>

<select class="admin__control-select">
    <option value="defaultValue">Default</option>
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="remove">Remove</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Remove All" onclick="selectFunction()" />
```

```
querySelectorAll()
```

returns the elements so you have to loop over them and set the value property.